# How to Parse this string to array object with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

"[[SZ000001,平安银行,PAYH,1],[SZ000002,万  科Ａ,WKA,1],[SZ000004,国农科技,GNKJ,1]]"

I want to use regex translate above string like -->

'[["SZ000001","平安银行","PAYH",1],["SZ000002","万  科Ａ","WKA",1],["SZ000004","国农科技","GNKJ",1]]'

I need use JSON.parse() to translate as a array object.
Some one can help me?

Comment: It would be easier to make the data source use JSON.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't bother with a regex when you can easily `.split()` it and `.map()` it, thus producing an array of arrays as output without needing `JSON.parse()`:

```js
var input = "[[SZ000001,平安银行,PAYH,1],[SZ000002,万 科Ａ,WKA,1],[SZ000004,国农科技,GNKJ,1]]";

var output = input.slice(2,-2).split("],[").map(s => s.split(","));

console.log(output);
```

Further reading:

- [String `.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)
- [String `.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [Array `.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)